# Patching a more than one cable in a patch panel

Tags: home-networking, patch-panel

I have attached picture to help explain. I just moved into a house and it is networked. The wall panels state CAT5 on them, but the patch panel looks like it is more setup for a phone (I think). I don't have any of my stuff except what I packed (no tools crimpers,toner,etc..). I never worked with a patch panel, but I thought I could just take another cable and punch it down on top of the cables (almost as just extending the wire to an end that is crimped) and plugging that into an un-managed switch I have (netgear gs105e). I did this to all of them (I am not sure which cable goes where. no tools) and tried to get a connection, but it did not work.

Upstairs I have my an access point connected to my firewall and to one of the walls ports. My last house was like this, but the ends were not punched down so I terminated them and just plugged them into the switch without any issues.

I have 2 thoughts I can't punch down 2 cables like this and will have to pull the cables out and terminate them. The other thought is the cables are the issue. I just went out and bought a couple and used ones that I already had. The ones I bought are cat6 terminated in t-568b while the ones I had are cat5 (I believe, they are old) ,terminated in t-568a. I didn't think it mattered, because the switch I have can do auto-mdix.
[Patch-Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV5CR.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The board those cables are punched into is for telephone.  To use the cables for ethernet you will need to remove them and terminate them either to a male or female RJ45 terminal.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that if I punched it down it would just act like a make shift extender. Still waiting on my stuff to come so will have to terminate it at that time.  Thanks for the help